# Si je pense **à** quelque chose, pourquoi dit-on « t'en penses quoi » au lieu de « t'y penses quoi »?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, en, y

Je sais que le pronom « en » est utilisé quand on remplace quelque chose qui commence avec « de ».

Par exemple :

> - Tu parlais de ça ?
> - Oui, j'en parlais.

Et on utilise « y » pour remplacer quelque chose commençant avec « à », encore par exemple

> - Tu est allé à Paris?
> - Oui, j'y suis allé

Donc, je suis troublé par le fait que bien que l'on dise « je pense **à** quelque chose », on dit aussi, « t'**en** penses quoi » si, par exemple, on veut l'avis de quelqu'un à propos de quelque chose. Est-ce que c'est expression est idiomatique, ou peut-être y a-t-il une règle ou exception que je ne connais pas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En fait, il y a ici confusion entre deux constructions du verbe [*penser*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/penser).

**Penser à qqc** (Sens IV.A.1-4.): ici "avoir présent à l'esprit"

**Penser qqc de qqc** (Sens II.A.2.b.α) "Avoir pour jugement à propos de qqc".

La question qui t'interpelle est construite avec ce second tour et interroge à propos du "qqc" complément direct. À moins que le complément indirect ne soit exprimé explicitement, il est normal (voir la réponse détaillée de reyedy) que le pronom *en* apparaisse.

Answer (score 4):

La phrase sur laquelle tu bases ton raisonnement est utilisée dans un contexte incorrect. En réalité, la question associée à

> Je pense à quelque chose.

est :

> À quoi penses-tu ?

La question que tu as voulu y associer s'utilise dans le contexte suivant :

> – Pour les vacances, je propose de partir en Espagne. Qu'**en** penses-tu/T'**en** penses quoi ? *[Pourrait également s'écrire "Que penses-tu de cette idée ?"]*
>
> – Je pense que **c**'est une bonne idée.

Ici, ***en*** et ***c***' font tous deux référence à l'idée de partir en Espagne.

Quant à la règle précise, la voici ([source + exemples complémentaires](https://www.bonjourdefrance.com/exercices/contenu/20/grammaire/573.html)) :

Le pronom **en** s'utilise :

- Pour remplacer un nom introduit par *de*.

> Vous avez envie de chocolat ? Oui, nous **en** avons envie.

- Pour remplacer un nom introduit par un article partitif ou un article défini.

> Que pensent-il de ce film ? Ils en pensent beaucoup de bien.

Le pronom **y** s'utilise :

- Pour remplacer un nom introduit par *a*.

> Est-ce que vous participez au tournoi de football dimanche ? Oui, nous y participons.

- Pour remplacer un nom de lieu.

> Partez-vous en Australie cet été ? Oui, nous y partons pour deux mois.

Enfin, pour mieux retenir les différents cas de figure, voici un petit schéma trouvé [ici](https://nathaliefle.com/pronoms-en-y-confusions/) :

[image: schema]

Answer (score 3):

Ce n'est pas une exception. Il y a plusieurs manières d'utiliser le verbe *penser*. Si on le construit sous la forme « penser à quelque chose », le pronom correspondant est « y penser ». Si on le construit sous la forme « penser quelque chose de quelque chose », les pronoms correspondants sont « en penser quoi ».

« Penser à quelque chose » signifie avoir un sujet en tête.

> Je pense **à mes examens**. J'**y** pense.

« Penser à quelque chose » peut aussi vouloir dire s'en souvenir.

> J'ai pensé **à fermer la porte**. J'**y** ai pensé.

« Penser quelque chose d'un sujet » signifie avoir une opinion sur le sujet. C'est le cas dans « t'en penses quoi ? ».

> Que penses-tu **du film que nous avons vu hier** ? Qu'**en** penses-tu ?   (registre soutenu)
> Tu penses quoi **du film qu'on a vu hier** ? T'**en** penses quoi ?   (registre familier)

Avec cette construction, il est assez rare d'avoir à la fois les deux compléments sous une forme longue. Dans la question ci-dessus, on précise « du film … » parce que sinon on ne saurait pas à quoi la question s'applique : « que/quoi » n'apporte pas assez d'information. En général, si l'opinion est exprimée, on n'a pas besoin de dire séparément à quel sujet elle s'applique.

> Je pense que le scénario était intéressant, mais le film était trop long.

On n'a pas besoin de rappeler « je pense *du film* ». « Je pense du film qu'il était trop long » est correct, mais un peu maladroit. Si on a besoin de préciser qu'on donne son opinion sur le film, on dirait normalement « Je pense que le film était trop long ». Toutefois, dans une réponse à une question comme « que penses-tu du film », il est assez fréquent d'utiliser le pronom « en », même s'il ne change pas le sens. C'est une forme d'emphase modérée.

> Je pense qu'il était trop long.
> J'en pense qu'il était trop long.